# Why is my AWS EC2 disk space always full?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I was using a `m5.large` instance with 16 GB storage until yesterday. Now, I've switched to `m5.xlarge` (I'm switching between the two as and when required) and expanded to 30GB of EBS volume.

This is my volume now:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.8G   52K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1   30G   29G  791M  98% /
```

I'm not sure why the Used space is 29GB all of a sudden! If I run this command to get the largest directories, this is what I get `du -hs * / | sort -n -r | head -n 5`:

```
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3249/task/3249/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3249/task/3249/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3249/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3249/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory

896M    index
552M    Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
224M    spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
124K    nltk_data
30M     scala-2.11.6
```

It all sums up to less than 2GB. How can I see what is using my disk space?

Comment: With parameters did you run the du command?

Comment: @Spiff updated answer

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/256619/df-shows-all-space-taken-but-du-doesnt-add-up

Comment: Is the link I posted relevant?

Comment: not really, the commands do not solve my problem

Comment: Don't use the `-h` parameter on `du`. As you can see from the output you pasted, sort doesn't recognize that `124K` isn't larger than `30M`.

Comment: @kdgregory makes an excellent point.  You're hiding data from yourself with `head`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.